# python - parse text to algebric equation

Tags: python

I have to convert the below problem statement into algebraic equation:

The age of father 10 years ago was thrice the age of his son. Ten years hence, father's age will be twice that of his son.

Any suggestions

Comment: this has nothing to do with python ... it's just math

Comment: I fear for you if you cant solve grade 4 math

Comment: Let the ages of father and son 10 years ago be 3x and x years respectively.

Then, (3x + 10) + 10 = 2[(x + 10) + 10]

 3x + 20 = 2x + 40

 x = 20. Where is the Python in this though ?

Comment: Convert it using Python?

Comment: (x-10)=3y and am voting to close this

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let the name of the dad be Bob and the son be Christopher. I think that the perfect solution for you would be Wolfram|Alpha alonside with its very simple Python API:

This requires of course [wolframalpha package installed](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/wolframalpha).

```
>>> import wolframalpha
```

Following line assumes you are having your own [Wolfram|Alpha API AppID](https://developer.wolframalpha.com/portal/apisignup.html). [Read more about terms of use in your applications](http://products.wolframalpha.com/api/termsofuse.html).

```
>>> client = wolframalpha.Client(app_id)
```

Now we can define our problem in a language of apples. We assume that Bobby is 10 years younger than Bob, same for Chris and Christopher.

```
>>> problem = '''Bobby has 3 times the number of apples as Chris has.
Bob has 10 more apples than Bobby has.
Christopher has 10 more apples than Chris has.
Bob has 2 times the number of apples as Christopher has.'''
```

The results are available in seconds:

```
>>> res = client.query(problem)
>>> for pod in res.pods:
...     if pod.title == 'Results':
...             print pod.text
... 
Bob has 40 apples.
```

And here are equations too:

```
>>> for pod in res.pods:
...     if pod.title == 'Equations with variables':
...         for i in pod:
...             print i.text
... 
bobb = 3 × chris
bob = bobb+10
christ = chris+10
bob = 2 × christ
```

Where `bobb` means Bob age 10 years ago (Bobby), `chris` means Christopher 10 years ago (Chris), `bob` means Bob and `christ` means Christopher (after 10 years).

Good luck and have fun!